# Sales Order status not changing after shipment created

Tags: acumatica

I am creating shipment of type Transfer from the custom screen, using below code, shipment is creating successfully but status in Sales Order screen is not updating, and also it is not allowing me to create shipment from Sales Order screen again because it already has an open shipment.

The status is getting updated when I confirm shipment.

```
soShipmentGraph.CreateShipment(soOrderGraph.Document.Current, graph.Document.Current.SiteID, graph.Document.Current.ShipDate, false, SOOperation.Issue, created);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status is updated towards the end of the CreateShipment method based on SOOrder.UpdateShipmentCntr field value if no exception were thrown during shipment creation:

```
if (order.OpenShipmentCntr > 0)
{
   order.Status = SOOrderStatus.Shipping;
   order.Hold = false;
   soorder.Update(order);
}
```

The OpenShipmentCntr field is updated by the SOShipmentEntry.UpdateShipmentCntr method:

```
protected virtual void UpdateShipmentCntr(PXCache sender, object Row, short? Counter)
{
    SOOrder order = (SOOrder)PXParentAttribute.SelectParent(sender, Row, typeof(SOOrder));
    if (order != null)
    {
        order.ShipmentDeleted = (Counter == -1) ? true : (bool?)null;
        order.ShipmentCntr += Counter;
        if (((SOOrderShipment)Row).Confirmed == false)
        {
            order.OpenShipmentCntr += Counter;
        }
        soorder.Cache.SetStatus(order, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
    }
}
```

When creating the shipment, SOShipmentEntry should insert a SOOrderShipment record that links SOOrder (Sales Order) with SOShipment (Shipment) records. The SOOrderShipment should be visible in the Orders tab of the shipment:

[image]

After insertion of the SOOrderShipment record the SOOrderShipment RowInserted event in SOShipmentEntry is raised:

```
protected virtual void SOOrderShipment_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateShipmentCntr(sender, e.Row, (short)1);
}
```

I couldn't determine the reason why the status won't change so I'd suggest to debug the steps leading to sales order status change.

Comment: Thanks HB_Acumatica, this solved my issue.
if (order.OpenShipmentCntr > 0)
{
   order.Status = SOOrderStatus.Shipping;
   order.Hold = false;
   soorder.Update(order);
}